# showing the error when connecting the api to react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, apiconnect, yelp-fusion-api

I want to connect react native project to an api. but it showing the error

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.restaurantData.map')

```
export default function RestaurantItems(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
                {props.restaurantData.map((restaurant, index) => (
                    <View key={index} style={{
                        marginTop: 10,
                        padding: 15,
                        backgroundColor: 'white'
                    }}>
                        <RestaurantImage image={restaurant.image_url} />
                        <RestaurantInfo
                            name={restaurant.name}
                            rating={restaurant.rating} />
                    </View>
                ))}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

console and check props.restaurantData.map